# Share folder with different password than log in password

Tags: security

In Microsoft Windows when we share a folder with password protection it uses the windows log in password by default. Can we share something with a password different from the user log in password so that others need not know my user log in password?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Security is about permissions granted to accounts, not about passwords stuck to shares.

Add other user account/password to the system, give that account permission to the share, and give them those credentials.